# Creating a temp table without using SELECT INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am aware that I can use `SELECT * INTO` statements to create temp tables.

However, is there any way to create temp tables using just a SELECT statement?

Let's say I have some SQL like `SELECT * FROM Customers`, is it possible to write a query like below to create the temp table?

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp as (SELECT * FROM Customers)
```

Comment: What scenario are you facing where you want to do it that way?

Comment: `CREATE TABLLE..INSERT INTO..SELECT`  construct

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simple answer is: No, you can't do what you've written in your question.

You can create and populate a temp table \ table variable in 2 ways:

**With a SELECT INTO:**

```
SELECT *
INTO #TEMP
FROM Customers
WHERE 1=2 -- no matches will create an empty table
```

This will take the columns and data types from the source table and create a temp table based on them.

**Define the table up front as a variable or temp table:**

```
-- table variable
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (Col1 int, Col2 int...);
-- or a temp table
CREATE TABLE #Temp (Col1 int, Col2 int...)

INSERT INTO @tmp (Col1, Col2...)
SELECT Col1, Col2...
FROM Customers
```

With this you have to define the table columns and types up front.

Comment: Hi Tanner, Thank you for your response.

Comment: You can also create a temp table from a table or view using: 
`SELECT TOP(0) * INTO #Temp FROM Customers`

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can do exactly what you have.

If a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE Region = 'UK';
```

gives the results you want, you can create a new table with the same structure containing these results like this:

```
CREATE TABLE UK_Customers AS
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE Region = 'UK';
```

Depending on exactly what you're trying to do you might want to look at CREATE VIEW to create "virtual" tables.

Comment: Hi Tony, THank you for your response. When I tried using the code what you have mentioned, I am getting error as incorrect syntax near 'as'. Can you please help? Is it working for you?